# Read and write Excel File by retaining all style, images, merged cells, colors, 3d template and symbols

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

I've a requirement where excel file will be fetched from File to LWC component in order to read, update and download the excel file. Below is the sample code for both Apex and LWC using sheetjs.
Any other Java script libraries for LWC?
I'm unable to download the excel file by maintaining the formats (all style, images, merged cells, colors, 3d template and symbols). Input excel file has different tabs with 3d template and symbols and photos, but missing those formats when downloading the same file.Please help me here.
Apex Class:

```
//Fetch Library Id
            
ContentWorkspace libraryRec  =[SELECT Id, Name, Description, CreatedDate, RootContentFolderId, WorkspaceType, DeveloperName FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = :setting.Folder_Library_Name__c LIMIT 1];

            //Fetch File stored in Library
            ContentDocument contentDoc = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Title, Description, ContentSize, FileType, SharingOption FROM ContentDocument WHERE ParentId = :libraryRec.Id AND Title = :setting.File_Name__c LIMIT 1];

            List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [
                SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Description, 
                ContentDocument.Title, LinkedEntityId 
                FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                WHERE LinkedEntityId = :libraryRec.Id AND ContentDocumentId = :contentDoc.Id
            ];

            if(!contentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()){
                ContentVersion cv = [
                    SELECT VersionData 
                    FROM ContentVersion 
                    WHERE ContentDocumentId = :contentDoc.Id 
                    AND IsLatest = true
                    LIMIT 1
                ];
                // System.debug(cv.VersionData);
                fileDetails.fileData = cv.VersionData;
                fileDetails.fileName = contentDoc.Title + FILE_TYPE_BY_EXTENSION.get(contentDoc.FileType);

            }
```

LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire , api} from 'lwc';
import readFileFromRecord from '@salesforce/apex/ExcelConnectorController.readFileFromRecord';
import getRecordData from '@salesforce/apex/ExcelConnectorController.getRecordData';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import sheetjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/sheetjs';
// import filesaveJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/FileSaver';

let XLS = {};
export default class ExcelConnectorLwc extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track acceptedFormats = ['.xls', '.xlsx'];
    @track recordDataObject ={};
    @track aoa;
    fileName;

    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, sheetjs )//, loadScript(this, filesaveJS )
        ]).then(() => {
            XLS = XLSX;
            this.readFromFile();
        })
        .catch((error) => {

            console.error('An error occurred while processing the script file :' + JSON.stringify(error));
    
          });
    }

     readFromFile() {
        readFileFromRecord({recordId: this.recordId})
        .then(result => {
            let returnVal = result.fileData;
            // console.log('returnVal:'+JSON.stringify(returnVal));
            this.fileName =  result.fileName 
            // let recordIdStr = this.recordId;
            // console.log('recordIdStr:'+recordIdStr);
            if(returnVal){
                let workbook = XLS.read(returnVal, {type:'binary'});
                const outputFilePath = 'output_file.xlsx';
                // Write the output file
                XLS.writeFile(workbook, outputFilePath, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: false, type: 'binary' });
                return;

 })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('returnVal error:'+JSON.stringify(error));
        })
    }
```